# Can't remove white spaces from a string?

Tags: c#

Hi i have a decimal value witch i'm trying to remove the white space when the value is over a thousand.

When a value is returned with over a thousand the number is returned something like "2 000", the white space is causing problems.

I have tried replace and trim and just can't find a way to remove the white spaces.

```
    decimal fee = AdministrationDataManager.AdminMarkupForPriceSelect(price, isProduct, companyId);
    string Fee = (fee.ToString("N2"));
    string newFee = Fee.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    newFee = newFee.Trim();
    return (newFee);
```

Comment: instead of replace just use string newfee=fee.trim()

Comment: That should work fine. Are you sure it's actually a space and not some other character? What culture are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formatting string `"N2"` format numbers with thousand separators. If you don't want thousand separators, use `"F2"` instead.

```
decimal Fee = 12345678.456M;
Fee.ToString("N2"); // 12,345,678.46 (Only an example)
Fee.ToString("F2"); // 12345678.46 (may also be 12345678,46, depending on culture)
```

[See MSDN for more.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

There is really no point to try to replace thousand separators using `string.Replace`, because it can be different on different computers.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `fee.ToString("N2")` if you don't want the thousands separator in the first place. Simply use `fee.ToString()` to get it in the format you want.